# Python error in pyzbar, Unable to find zbar shared library

Tags: python, qr-code, zbar

I am using a CentOS server and when I try to use pyzbar I get an error saying

```
App 13884 output:     from fatoora import Fatoora
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fatoora/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
App 13884 output:     from .fatoora import Fatoora
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fatoora/fatoora.py", line 14, in <module>
App 13884 output:     from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
App 13884 output:     from .wrapper import (
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 139, in <module>
App 13884 output:     zbar_version = zbar_function(
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
App 13884 output:     return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
App 13884 output:     libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
App 13884 output:   File "/home/flickbil/virtualenv/app/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py", line 65, in load
App 13884 output:     raise ImportError('Unable to find zbar shared library')
App 13884 output: ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

I don't face any issue in Windows system but in CentOS who can I fix this error? Which file do I need to upload to server and give path to?